# What IP's should be whitelisted for a managed ChromeOS device?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

Is there an equivalent to netblocks and/or SPF records (https://support.google.com/a/answer/60764?hl=en), or simply documentation stating what communication from a managed ChromeOS device should be whitelisted on a firewall to allow full functionality?

We have a client who requires full documentation of all communication in/out of the device and would like to use Chromeboxes for the application.

The SSL whitelist domains here appears related (perhaps simply whitelisting all IP's associated would work?): https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3504942#sslinspection

Comment: should probably move this to SuperUser

Comment: agreed, or probably ServerFault. Didn't appear to be any Chrome OS related community there, so I posted here first.

Comment: agreed, flagged it :) I'm sure you will get additional help there.

Answer (score 1):

As [provided](https://github.com/google/gfw-deployments/blob/master/apps/utils/GoogleAppsWildcardedDomains.txt) (subject to change at any time) by Google:

```
*doubleclick.net*
*gmail.com*
*google-analytics.com*
*google.com*
*googleadservices.com*
*googleapis.com*
*googleusercontent.com*
*gstatic.com*
*ggpht.com*
*ytimg.com*
```

Officially, Google does not recommend or support using a static list ([page 20 of the networking guide](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//support/enterprise/static/gapps/docs/admin/en/nftf/networking_guide/gapps_networking_guide.pdf)).